# generating expressions from python pandas dataframe/dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pandas, expression

I'm trying to generate few expressions from a dataframe
Here is my data set

```
df_scr_cns = {'Subject': ['MATH', 'PSY'], 
        'CNS': ['min', 'max']}
df_scr_cns_d = pd.DataFrame(df_scr_cns, columns = ['Subject', 'CNS'])
```

The output I'm looking for is 
print and execute the following statements

```
MATH_CNS_BASIS = MIN
MATH_CNS_BASIS = MAX
```

How do I do this in python using dictionaries or lists

Comment: you forgot to ask the question...

Comment: I edited the question..basically i have few strings in colA (ex:MATH) and few strings in colB(MIN). I'm trying to generate expressions like MATH_CNS_BASIS = MIN

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your expected output has a typo

```
MATH_CNS_BASIS = MIN
PSY_CNS_BASIS = MAX
```

You can use the input dictionary directly by

```
from itertools import izip
for subject, cns in izip(df_scr_cns['Subject'], df_scr_cns['CNS']):
    print "%s_CNS_BASIS = %s" % (subject, cns.upper())
```